# How to set initial value on useRef<HTMLInputElement> - ReactJs + Typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I would like to set a number as initial value on  `useRef<HTMLInputElement>`.

I don't need to use `useState<number>()` because the field is a simple counter.

Here is my typescript code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const productAmountRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  const handleReduceClick = () => {
    productAmountRef.current.value -= 1;
  }

  const handleAddClick = () => {
   productAmountRef.current.value += 1;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SomeWrapper>

        <ReduceButton onClick={handleReduceClick}/>

          <input disabled={true} ref={productAmountRef}/>

        <AddButton  onClick={handleAddClick}/>


      </SomeWrapper>
    </>
  )

}
```

For obvious reasons, when the `onClick` function is triggered, the value is a `NaN`.

My doubt is, how can I set a Initial Value on `useRef<HTMLInputElement>`? As I said and as you saw, it need to be a number.

Is this possible?

Comment: *I don't need to use useState<number>() because the field is a simple counter.* I'm not gonna say you're right or wrong since I don't know your use-case. I'll just say that this sentence alone makes very little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the initial value using the `defaultValue` attribute:

```
<input disabled={true} ref={productAmountRef} defaultValue={3} />
```

Or use `useState()` and render the number without the use of an input:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [productAmount, setProductAmount] = useState(0);

  const handleReduceClick = () => {
    setProductAmount(val => val - 1);
  }

  const handleAddClick = () => {
   setProductAmount(val => val + 1);
  }

  return (
    <SomeWrapper>
      <ReduceButton onClick={handleReduceClick}/>

      <div>{productAmount}</div>

      <AddButton  onClick={handleAddClick}/>
    </SomeWrapper>
  )
}
```